# Libreoffice 4.1 cannot create UnoUrlResolver

Tags: python, python-2.7, libreoffice

I am following the example for hello_world.py from [here](http://www.openoffice.org/udk/python/python-bridge.html#modes). The example works fine in Libreoffice3, but it failed with error in Libreoffice4.1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello_world.py", line 18, in <module>
    desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext( "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop",ctx)
    __main__.RuntimeException: Binary URP bridge disposed during call
```

Why? And where can I find tutorials regarding python/python-uno for libreoffice4? The interlinking documentation and tutorial between libreoffice and apache openoffice really hurts my head

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading to LibreOffice 4.2